# Spring Boot Called several time on Payara Srver

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, payara

I'm new to Spring and I'm trying to setup a application by using spring-boot-starter-web. The application can started successfully but I found that the application will start several times when I deployed it to Payara Server.

Below is the part of message printed by Payara Server.

```
Initializing Soteria 1.1-b01.payara-p5 for context '/springweb'

Registering WebSocket filter for url pattern /*]]

ServletContext.log():2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath

    .   ____          _            __ _ _
   /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
  ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
   \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
    '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
   =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

:: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.4)

INFO 2470 --- [in-listener(56)] springweb.Application  : Starting Application using Java 11.0.11 on 192.168.0.1 with PID 2470 (/usr/share/payara/payara5/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/springweb/WEB-INF/classes/springweb/Application.class started by root in /usr/share/payara/payara5/glassfish/domains/domain1/config)

INFO 2470 --- [in-listener(56)] springweb.Application  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"

WebModule[/springerb] ServletContext.log():Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext

INFO 2470 --- [in-listener(56)] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1975 ms

INFO 2470 --- [in-listener(56)] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: ServletContext resource [/index.html]

WARN 2470 --- [in-listener(56)] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates, check your Thymeleaf configuration, or set spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=false)

WARN 2470 --- [in-listener(56)] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: b200e25a-ee5a-49f1-b7f4-047aa11fa4fb

This generated password is for development use only. Your security configuration must be updated before running your application in production.

INFO 2470 --- [in-listener(56)] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@78d61d6d, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2de8cf84, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@6e79b72e, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1aca9626, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@387eb143, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@39199309, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@29d0bc34, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@34c4cf9e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@5603f50, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@1d190e55, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@30f8298b, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7b7f364, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@5e208791, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1ab27ca7, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@330305b, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@196974a2

INFO 2470 --- [in-listener(56)] springweb.Application  : Started Application in 5.942 seconds (JVM running for 274786.407)

Initializing Mojarra |version.string| for context '/springweb'

Initializing Soteria 1.1-b01.payara-p5 for context '/springweb'

Registering WebSocket filter for url pattern /*

ServletContext.log():2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath

    .   ____          _            __ _ _]]
   /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \]]
  ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \]]
   \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )]]
    '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /]]
   =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/]]

:: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.4)]]

.
.
.
.
```

And the dependency that I used :

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                      <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-loader</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
            <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>                 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And I use the annotation @SpringBootApplication to start the

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have removed or changed the version of dependency but it can't solve the problem. I have no idea why it will restart the application and some function such as schedulers because it will be initiated multi-times.

The version of Payara Server is 5.2021.1 and the Java version is 11

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude the tomcat embedded server in your pom.xml like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```